# private String[] categories; storing the datatype of category as tinyblob

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using private String[] categories in the entity object, but in the database the datatype of categories gets defined as tinyblob and when I try to add categories or try to fetch it, it throws an error.

How can I store it as a string array?

Comment: my recommendation: not. it's not a String, so you shouldn't treat it as such.

Comment: I want categories as string array in database, how to do it? @Stultuske

Comment: modify your database. If it's just a small text representing a category, there is no reason to declare it a tinyblob

Comment: do you let spring-data create the database tables? if so, then your mapping is probably incorrect or missing. also, mysql has no "array" datatype, so there can be no basic mapping